# Two definitions of Taylor polynomials

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I'm studying a book which states

> Given a function $f:I\to \mathbb R$, $n$ times derivable in the point
>   $a\in I$, the *Taylor polynomial* of order $n$ of $f$ in the point $a$
>   is the polynomial:
>
> $$p(h)=f(a)+f'(a)\cdot h+\frac{f''(a)}{2!}\cdot
>  h^2+\ldots+\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}\cdot h^n$$
>
> This is the only polynomial of degree $\le n$ whose derivatives (from
>   the order $0$ to the order n) in the point $0$ coincide with the
>   corresponding derivatives of $f$ in the point $a$

However, I saw in another sources ([this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) and [this](http://www.math.smith.edu/~rhaas/m114-00/chp4taylor.pdf)) that the Taylor polynomial is given by:

$$p(x)=f(a)+f'(a)\cdot (x-a)+\frac{f''(a)}{2!}\cdot (x-a)^2+\ldots+\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}\cdot (x-a)^n$$

I would like to know why these polynomials are equivalent, i.e., why we can call both of Taylor polynomial, I'm really confused.

Thanks.

Comment: The definition of $p$ is slightly different. The one that is normally used is the second one with $(x-a)$. As Dmoreno points out, the difference is that $h$ is replaced by $(x-a)$ on the left side.

Comment: $h$ represents the difference between the base point $a$ and the actual point you want to evaluate. Your book is treats the polynomial as a function of $h$ (how far you are from $a$) rather than $x$ (the actual location). I have only really seen the formula with $x$, but the one with $h$ is not wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The two $p(x)$ are different. The second one approximate your function $f(x)$ around $a$, in other words your second $p$ is
$$
p(x) \approx f(x)
$$
your first $p(h)$ does not, but $p(h+a)$ does.